# Class activation mapping using inception-v3 network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

I am using the technique of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07953.pdf
to localize food objects. The difference is that I am using the next generation of google-net, inception-v3 network. For the localization problem, in the paper they modify the network cutting the last 2 inception modules to receive 14x14 grid and by adding a conv-layer and a GAP they achieve precise localization of food. In my network, the inception modules are not 9 like google-net, but 10. I thought that cutting the last 3 inception modules to receive a 17x17 grid for the localization would result to similar localization but I have not achieved this yet. You think that's a good technique or I should modify the network in other way? An opinion from here would be very helpful to make the right experiments. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Unfortunately, your post seems to be asking for opinion and discussion, which is not suited for this platform. Were you to give your full code, it'd be code review which we also don't do. Do you have a specific, conceptual question that can be answered using facts? Till then, community votes, please: opinion-based?

Comment: My basic question is what would be the most effective modification of the network. I thought that I could receive an answer from stackexchange. Where can I ask?

Comment: If you're not willing to fiddle with your network and experiment, I suggest you stick to the design of the paper. Either you want to use their result as a black-box, or you are willing to do some research in order to improve on their results. In the latter case, you should be the one doing the research, not us. (Not to mention that it would be much more difficult for us, since you already programmed the system.)

Comment: I am doing the latter and I have done a lot of experiments, but I am not getting better results, so I wanted a second opinion in stackexchange. I am not asking for a solution. The only thing I want is a recommendation.